# VSCode add cursor shortcut in linux not working

Tags: linux, ubuntu, visual-studio-code

I'm currently working on a fresh install of Ubuntu 22. I'm coming from the newest distro of Pop_OS. I have two VSCode shortcuts that aren't working - 'ctrl+alt+UpArrow/DownArrow' aren't working. I use them to add cursors above/below. I've run into this issue before and it was because of CentOS shortcuts to change the workspace. I checked using `gsetting` and I had the same issue so I went and changed the shortcuts using the following commands:

`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-left "['<Control><Super>Left']"`

`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-right "['<Control><Super>Right']"`

After that, the ctrl+alt+[left/right] shortcut stopped working for changing workspaces, which is expected, but it still didn't fix my VSCode issue. So I checked the shortcuts for changing workspaces again using

```
gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings
```

Which still lists the shortcuts for changing workspaces as the original shortcuts. They didn't update after setting them, even though they don't work anymore. Also, I originally copied the VSCode keybindings json file over, so I went and tried to set the 'add cursor up/down' keybindings in VSCode manually and I was able to type 'ctrl' and 'alt' with it regesitering in the VSCode keybinding prompt, but up and down won't register. However, left and right registered fine. Also, the up and down keys do work.

Note: I'm using an HP Envy x360 laptop

Comment: Sorry, what's the question? Check out [ask] if you want tips. If you want to ask about the OS, that's probably [off-topic](/help/on-topic) and you should ask on [ubuntu.se] instead. And why are you talking about up/down then left/right? Is there a typo or did I misunderstand something?

Comment: Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) **into your question post**. What do you see when you [troubleshoot your keybindings](//github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/Keybinding-Issues)? Please paste the relevant parts of what you see into a code block in your question post.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue Sam (on Manjaro with VS Codium v1.84.2)

Here's the (edited for space) keyboard logging output for Ctrl+Alt+UpArrow:

2023-12-07 00:27:40.461 [info] [KeybindingService]: / Received  keydown event - modifiers: [ctrl], code: ControlLeft, keyCode: 17, key: Control

2023-12-07 00:27:40.635 [info] [KeybindingService]: / Received  keydown event - modifiers: [ctrl,alt], code: AltLeft, keyCode: 18, key: Alt
2023-12-07 00:27:40.636 [info] [KeybindingService]: \ Keyboard event cannot be dispatched in keydown phase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I want to apologize for the confusion in my original question. The questions, summarized, was why isn't my VSCode shortcut working after removing Ubuntu keybindings that were using the same modifier keys. It turns out I had missed some keybindings. Here are the steps I used, using `gsettings` command, on Ubuntu 22.xx.

Step 1:

- Find where the keybindings are. For me, `gsettings list-schemas | grep key` listed everything under gsettings with key in it and `org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings` is the schema that holds my keybindings.

Step 2:

- Using `gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings` will list an action and its keybinding/s. Having prior experience with my issue, I grep'd for 'workspace' because the workspace shortcuts had been my issue before. However, a good way to start would be to look for the specific keys that are used in the keybinding that's not working for you, i.e. `gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings | grep Ctrl\>\<Super` will return all the shortcuts with Ctrl+Super being used together.

Step 3:

- Change the shortcut using: `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings <keybinding name> "['keybinding 1','keybinding 2',...]"`

Step 4:

- Confirm the shortcut was changed using `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings <keybinding name>`

Comment: How did you determine the cause of the problem?